# Writing a Thesis paper

Tags: academic-writing

What to do if you feel stuck while writing? Feels like you cant write a single fresh line. I don't know much words and also I have grammatically issue as well.  Now that I am writing my discussion chapter I feel that I am totally stuck and I have no time to relax. I cant relax properly even. Don't understand how I will improve my writing and finish my project in a academic way?

Comment: sounds like writers block, sometimes the best thing to do is take a step back and give it a few minutes. clear your head and then try again after a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Your situation is somewhat unusual in that you are not writing in your primary language.

I would suggest that you organize your information in your primary language.

Make a list of what has to go in the discussion chapter and in what order.  Think of it as an outline. Write it out (or type it) in your primary language.

Write your discussion chapter in English according to your outline.  Your outline has everything in the correct order, so you just need to write English sentences to express the points in the outline.

This won't make writing the English parts any easier, but it relieves you of trying to organize your thoughts in a foreign language.

---

The suggestion above is something that I deal with daily.

I am an American, but I live in Germany.  Nearly everything I write at work is in German.

Before I write anything, I organize my thoughts in English.  Once I know what I need to say, I write the text in German.

I do **not** translate an English text into German, and you should **not** translate from your native language to English.

When you read in your own language, the words you read build a sort of model in your mind - a structure that has a particular feel and content.

The idea is to build that structure in your mind, then write an English text that will generate the same structure in your reader's mind.

Take for an example that I need to write a status report on a project at work.

I go through the current state of the project in my mind and collect all the relevant points.  If it is really complicated, I write a bullet list of those points - in English.

Once I have everything gathered, I write German sentences that express those points.  The written outline is only to make sure that I don't forget anything - like a checklist.

Since I'm working from a bullet list, there are no English sentences to translate.  The points in the list prompt me to write a certain thing in German, but there's not enough words in each list item that I could make a translation.

When all of the bullet points have been written in German, I write the connecting sentences to make paragraphs out of the individual sentences.

When all of that is done, I go over the whole thing and correct spelling and grammar problems.  When you correct spelling and grammar, do not concentrate on the content.  Read each sentence as though you were an English teacher grading spelling and grammar.

When that is clean, go back and read the whole thing for content.

- See if everything you needed to say is there.
- See if the connections between individual points are clear and correct.
- See if you have expressed in English that concept you had in your mind as you made the list in your native language.

---

You won't get your written text in English perfect.

I'll let you in on a secret:  Most native English speaking people won't, either. Does everyone write perfectly in your primary language?  Probably not.

You can make your English text pretty good.

Your goal is to express your information and plans clearly enough that your thesis will be understood.

To that end, you need to express yourself clearly.  If the grammar of a complex sentence causes you difficulties then you should write one or more simple sentences that you can get correct.

- Use clear, simple sentences.
- Check your spelling and punctuation carefully.  Punctuation has rules, and dictionaries are there for the spelling.
- Write in active voice as much as possible.  Active voice results in simpler sentences.

Comment: I understand your concerns that the OP may overuse the passive voice, but the passive voice does have a purpose, in that it puts the focus on the action and not who is doing the action. It is not realistic for most of the OP's sentences to be in the passive voice.

Comment: @TobyMak: "as much as possible." Passive voice can't always be avoided, but when you can the sentences are much simpler in structure. My views on formal writing come from my time in the military: Express your points clearly, avoid passive voice, tell them what you're going to tell them, tell them what you are telling them, tell them what you told them. Along with that is my daily experience in writing in a foreign lanuage. Simple, clear, correct will get you much farther than convoluted, obfuscated, and incorrect (regarding grammar and sentence structure.)